Are all Safe Account's Smart Save Accounts?
This might be a very beginner question. I'm looking through the Safe Core docs and it talks a lot about using Core to create a "Safe Smart Account", but in the docs for the Starter Kit, it only uses the term "Safe Account". In other instances, not having "Smart" makes it a very different product, so I want to make sure I fully understand what is being created.
And if the Safe I am creating is a "Smart Account", it should be relatively straight forward to "plug-in" different AA features like bundlers and paymasters into the created Safe, is that right?

The terms "Safe Account" and "Safe Smart Account" essentially refer to the same thing in this context. Safe Accounts are inherently "smart" because they are implemented as smart contracts on the blockchain. The distinction you're worried about (the presence or absence of "Smart" in the term) is not introducing a different product here. Safe Accounts are a type of Smart Contract Account, which is part of the broader Account Abstraction (AA) concept.
The core of Safe is built to allow for modularity and extensibility, making it ideal for advanced use cases like those Account Abstraction enables.
